# Como ler arquivo txt separado por "|" utilizando Python com a biblioteca Pandas?

Tags: python, data, pandas

Possuo um arquivo txt com a seguinte estrutura:

```
-----------------------------------
|SKU.   |DT.Compra|Dt.Chegada|SKTD|
|---------------------------------|
|100312 |20171202 |20180105  | 27 |
|89721  |20171202 |20180105  | 26 |
|192063 |20171205 |20180104  | 25 |
|182285 |20171205 |20180107  | 24 |
|32934  |20171210 |20180105  | 21 |
|43495  |20171202 |20180112  | 22 |
|4342   |20171202 |20180110  | 23 |
|3124   |20171204 |20180104  | 28 |
|43495  |20171207 |20180105  | 23 |
```

Como posso obter os dados em forma de dataframe e poder utilizar os dados?

Comment: Seria 20171202 um timestamp? Você sabe qual o formato desse valor para que seja possível fazer a conversão?

Comment: Teoricamente é uma string no formato 'YYYYmmDD'

Comment: user139757, encontrei a resposta. Irei editar a pergunta com a dúvida atual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o módulo `csv` para parsear automaticamente:

```
import csv
with open('seu_arquivo.txt', newline='') as f:
     # pular as linhas divisorias:
     f = (linha.strip('|') for linha in f if '---' not in linha) 
     cf = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|')
     df = pd.DataFrame(cf)
```